# How to run a python script on click of html button

Tags: python, html

I've read many articles but have had zero luck in finding a solution. I currently have a file called index.html that is executed when I run server.py. I'm just running this locally and have two separate .py files within the same folder and I'm trying to have them execute upon clicking one of the two buttons.

Here is what I have pieced together from the articles that I've read (index.html):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <iframe name="hidden_iframe" width="0" height="0" style="border:none"></iframe>
    <form method="post" action="out.php" target="hidden_iframe">

        <input type="submit" name="Run Hello.py" value="Run Hello.py" onClick=" <? exec('Hello.py'); ?> ">
        <input type="submit" name="Run World.py" value="Run World.py" onClick=" <? exec('World.py'); ?> ">

    </form>


</body>
```

The buttons show up but when clicked they don't do anything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is hard to read or make sense of, because servers don't execute html files and a web page can't force a python program to run on the client.  If you want to run some python on the server whenever a web user clicks a particular button, you might use [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Comment: @Paul I was using flask towards the beginning but I guess after attempting to follow the various articles I was lead away from it. Thanks for the advice. At least now I know I was right the first time.

Comment: The easiest way is to learn about forms and how to use them with flask.  You can use the form to collect information from the visitor for the code that will run, and then send the result back to the visitor.

Comment: @Paul Great to know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you find it necessary to set up a web server for this? or did you just need the html and python files saved in the same folder and use the html file to start your scrip?